# Matplotlib graph displaying fewer ticks than requested

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I am using the following code to generate this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXq8e.png):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))

bins = np.arange(1, 22,1)
ax.hist(val, bins=bins, density=True, alpha = 1, zorder=1, edgecolor = 'w', color='grey', label = '10-min records')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major')
ax.set_xlabel("Wind speed (m/s)", fontsize=30)
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency", fontsize=30)
ax.set_xticks(range(1,23,1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,0.19,0.02))
ax.set_yticklabels([0.00, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18])
ax.legend(prop=dict(size=18))
fig.show()
```

But, when I add a Weibull distribution to the graph using the code below (in addition to the code above) my y-axis is rescaled and some of the ticks I requested do no longer show (see this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kp2S.png)). Why is that?

Weibull code:

```
xplot = np.linspace(0, max(bins), 1000)
(scale, a, shape, c) = stats.exponweib.fit(s18, f0=1, floc=0)
ax.plot(xplot, stats.exponweib.pdf(xplot, *stats.exponweib.fit(s56, 1, 1, scale=1, loc=0)), zorder=3, color = "black", linewidth=1.6, label="Weibull fit\n (a={:.4g} ; c={:.5g})".format(a, c))
```

Comment: This might not be the reason, but are you adding the Weibull distribution before or after manipulating the ticks and labels? I would put your new code immediately after the histogram and before ticks_params

Comment: Magical! I was indeed doing it after.... Thanks! Everything works now! :)